# Not able to change SharePoint calendar month view to week view in IOS mobile

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-view, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, apple-ios

I have created SharePoint site. also added one calendar list in site.if i open this into IOS mobile not able to change the week and month views in calendar.
it's working for some times.this page has no device channels.
is this a SharePoint default behavior?
suggest any idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: which version of SP?

Comment: SharePoint server 2013